# Few character was added when read email from Imap python

Tags: python, email, imap

I have a small script that reads Hotmail via the Imap server to get the latest email and parse the verification link for me.

I have converted the the raw email to UTF-8 but for some reason, some characters in the link were different from the original link I found in the normal browser mailbox

```
import imaplib
from urlextract import URLExtract

extractor = URLExtract()

email_pass = "mail|pass"
credentials = email_pass.split("|")
imap_host = "outlook.office365.com"
imap_user = ""+credentials[0]+""
imap_pass = ""+credentials[1]+""


imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, 993)
## login to server
imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

imap.select('Inbox')

result, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL') # ['FROM', 'email@outlook.example']
ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest email

result, data = imap.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") # fetch the email body (RFC822)

raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email - including headers and alternate payloads

decode = raw_email.decode(encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'strict')

#if "tester" in str(raw_email):
print(decode)
verify_url = extractor.find_urls(str(decode))
print(verify_url)
```

Here is the raw_email:

```
b'Received: from TY0PR06MB5659.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (2603:1096:400:275::10)\r\n by TYUPR06MB6196.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Wed, 10 Jan 2024\r\n 16:15:17 +0000\r\nReceived: from MW4PR04CA0120.namprd04.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:303:83::35)\r\n by TY0PR06MB5659.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (2603:1096:400:275::10) with\r\n Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,\r\n cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7181.17; Wed, 10 Jan\r\n 2024 16:15:15 +0000\r\nReceived: from MW2NAM12FT092.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com\r\n (2603:10b6:303:83:cafe::b7) by MW4PR04CA0120.outlook.office365.com\r\n (2603:10b6:303:83::35) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,\r\n cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7181.18 via Frontend\r\n Transport; Wed, 10 Jan 2024 16:15:14 +0000\r\nAuthentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 208.82.237.96)\r\n smtp.mailfrom=tester.org; dkim=pass (signature was verified)\r\n header.d=tester.org;dmarc=pass action=none\r\n header.from=tester.org;compauth=pass reason=100\r\nReceived-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of tester.org\r\n designates 208.82.237.96 as permitted sender)\r\n receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=208.82.237.96;\r\n helo=outbound.ashburn.tester.org; pr=C\r\nReceived: from outbound.ashburn.tester.org (208.82.237.96) by\r\n MW2NAM12FT092.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.181.163) with Microsoft SMTP\r\n Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id\r\n 15.20.7135.20 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 10 Jan 2024 16:15:14 +0000\r\nX-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:\r\n OriginalChecksum:8CCA0638BD9A1392B2AB59C0278333734304D205484BD261D568A461D62E9F23;UpperCasedChecksum:ED0971A4E94E53FDB170DAA72D0800FF9D556C2C50937DFDD8EC837B05395D7B;SizeAsReceived:954;Count:13\r\nReceived: outbound\r\nDKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 outbound.ashburn.tester.org 99DEC2005489E\r\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=tester.org;\r\n\ts=20220810-174317-nbvio1dp; t=1704903313;\r\n\tbh=Xpf9Q5wQvoz3IuPQQZ6kuvkxl8RcXhHtxgs7dz52IpE=;\r\n\th=MIME-Version:From:To:Subject:Date:From:To:Cc:Reply-To:Subject;\r\n\tb=d5JY7ZVcxzwnDAgpBMmp3a1j8AkewXsIjkeRYWdBtrCtjG4J4O+CEgCBmJavL2SAg\r\n\t Cpc8vbU1wUNndqU1MLyYavJmI4jH83CQAXJbLQqbcwKkagwe7uC4EhL9rR3EduiTqI\r\n\t yWWx6Ej4CksxpvPuqfryPOC2GURIQhoRctsZtQUE=\r\nReceived: outbound\r\nX-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.510 (Entity 5.510)\r\nFrom: "tester - automated message, do not reply" <robot@tester.org>\r\nTo: gossgen789485@hotmail.com\r\nSubject: tester account sign-up\r\nDate: Wed, 10 Jan 2024 16:15:13 +0000 (GMT)\r\nX-CL-Originating-Ip: 116.97.36.174\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n boundary="----------=_1704903313-1077319-54"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\nX-IncomingHeaderCount: 13\r\nMessage-ID:\r\n <8c19d4c9-8ebf-469a-a63f-ce1612f60961@MW2NAM12FT092.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com>\r\nReturn-Path: bounce-accounts@tester.org\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 10 Jan 2024 16:15:14.4014\r\n (UTC)\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:\r\n 8a80c21f-3ab1-45ae-95e6-08dc11f75405\r\nX-EOPAttributedMessage: 0\r\nX-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming\r\nX-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email\r\nX-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic:\r\n MW2NAM12FT092:EE_|TY0PR06MB5659:EE_|TYUPR06MB6196:EE_\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:\r\n MW2NAM12FT092.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous\r\nX-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 1/10/2024 4:12:18 PM\r\nX-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 8a80c21f-3ab1-45ae-95e6-08dc11f75405\r\nX-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true\r\nX-Sender-IP: 208.82.237.96\r\nX-SID-PRA: ROBOT@tester.ORG\r\nX-SID-Result: PASS\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 2\r\nX-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:4;\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Jan 2024 16:15:14.2608\r\n (UTC)\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 8a80c21f-3ab1-45ae-95e6-08dc11f75405\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:\r\n MW2NAM12FT092.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet\r\nX-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:\r\n 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: TY0PR06MB5659\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:03.2174270\r\nX-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.7181.013\r\nX-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:\r\n\tucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(5062000305)(920221119095)(90000117)(920221120095)(90005022)(91005020)(91035115)(9050020)(9100341)(944500132)(4810010)(4910033)(9910022)(9545005)(10170022)(9320005)(120001);\r\nX-Message-Info:\r\n\tqZelhIiYnPlXlI7es2YNEHv97rIX/LC80MwrGTvvdx3+mebjZADavuei11S1ENECFH2tJPoygRl5jqiRJ+kmWQfRHlcbiDMPcJ4LwUXuEQsNIuRDDMe98072/VrEji8GPBkOS9s4SVJduVn5uyo5xxcSs4DNLgrRCUMLpVGPXQ2EChq8M5OGHY1PbWp3p5O17+axNM+aIioE7KEu9sMYig==\r\nX-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0tMQ==\r\nX-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?UHlBUTFNclloZ3dwQUFpRUZhTTd5SURXcktTVjZUZnFML3NGRFBwT2VZZVVz?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?RkhlZFVaZlozdW04RXpMQzVEeXdXS3dDcTQzeDRpblF2NkEwN0pHTkQ0VVZm?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?MnFTMGdCRTZ1cUJvait6VThWS2FLODB0U1BocmI5Wk9wTkJOcnN3cDBSUFNh?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?SUVjckNUemlTOFRMaGpLOFQrOGloMTlQWGxpZlZnUXIzYmlQY1Z2OUZ2czY3?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?WHhWVG9EdkpNeG43NHZ3Y0tNR2ZzaGQ0MVZWMitDRnlsR2xNZnFIMDNodXhZ?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?WDdtVHYwTlNZQnhwWEdJVXUxM3BQeFA1WTJkU1JjU2UyaWdmd05FTVR5RFBZ?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?NzZ4OUlidXBaWFlmSThNcnFHc3h6M2FNQmZHenI5VEdXKzZNbk9IWldFYU9N?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?NkUxSktab3lxV3U3OGZtRlBmZW5CZFNqc0NnUWpjcFpxZVJYRmpFZTNiaXRL?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?TndKMGxSbXk0UUdlUzlOdTQ2aFJFSCtEQVErVUQ0czJiM2ZEMzhRTFdtNy8y?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?L1JBRUVlRlBqMDBJblJkNDVGOXB4L3M0cjdYZzRLZThxdFlxdjVVeEk2enFV?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?OUtrdXl2R2E3RVI1a3hicXpqNWlFNkY5STdlMjkrSlZmdk9HSUZycmQyWDVl?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?WkNQdU9vNVFpNUpEVHdDcFdhdzNEQk9VNnBBUk5uUG4wSHRUWDZPalNvZkdP?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?akVZRWRORW5tZFp4T1BvYldpdEwrUXI1YlZ3VVppT2RjSkVEM2JlMndsUGY2?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?eHRrOUJpNFNjOXliOWd1a1YwdU1RaU0rT0docm5Za093ZlJrRWhOanZGZnJp?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?VUwrQVYxRkRiSFE3OFFvNUNKQTFWOS93YjhBYlJXWlNIdFEyMUFnWmx0d2FK?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?VGhtVXZ5Rm9YNlNONG1vaDliVjg3aC9PK2Z3clNtaWUyai81T1hEc3ZxRy94?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?dndSOWYvZXpuNnRQOFNkN0dUSWNMNHhWeFlBSTNpT1RCVVgvd0pxUDFBOXN6?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?cGs4cERPZDBvVmt6S2RlbmFhRnJ5Sm4vTVd1Wk5zQVhkejEybXN0S3JwZXho?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?TXJEakxvOWF3clpxK0laQ1pnOVcrZkhzclMrdXFvQ3IzcVkxOEZ0ZURFVThs?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?a2VWUm9TYlZiT2FhbURoTDVDUDNQMmhDczdyTjJmMUJ5U2pGUSsxQW5MeUt3?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?ZEpxalNraHhsWVVjZnVKS1NaODNJcE13ajUvbWYyS1dOb0tyVTFQbEwrRUFh?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?MURYWjFkUlhoa1dtMjgwR1VVQUIvZlpDVEh5U1BRUEtrcTE0eTZmZk9QSHNq?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?b3Arc1BSbXBTdVpmUkN6cStBSzQzRDJ6MmtUaklDZmEyTlRsVzVLcGxzZXYw?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?KzR0aVBFQU1seFlVTGw3UG9zRFoyTFljTkFHVlg0NFFYa1RidHEzUXVRYnp1?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?eEJuTllXYzB4bHhWblZuKzZJTWdEdEt6WVA4M1R3dGxZcExxMFRZdlVyVVRm?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?NGhnemM1MXMrakZyc2QzakZuRlJwQThZaVEwclMraXQwL2pURkZxV0RDMkEy?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?MkMzQVZGLzhYSmNZSGh5Smd5NUZVUXJnU2x1U1RhTEp0aE55OTI1Yk1Ddld2?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?bWhndlM1QjhnQzdWZDhZK2hVazgxVjJhNnZaQUVqNEYzUU1vTEJiTnovOUY5?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?S29FWmJsbjFkRWg0ZXIyTXhyZkUrVnpSQmJlbHBzMWYrYUxtbUlERFVLOTFX?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?WGduTGthSEdLQTY5OWVVbVhHNDNsL1EwdDZnNHZIaTVsZ1NGZWxPMmYwMFo3?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?cDYzR1c3T1dLQUZOdUpUTXkzdnJGelNKcGI4cXQ1YmNORnBLVnpvaHdYMzhV?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?c0xLTGxKYWJuRVBmU0lZcUVlZEZhYlRrUzJSQ0lsOGIyNGlnUlRrbm1OcE5v?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?YWNsZnd2eVBwb2RYQ2VmakZkOGxIRGF6N1UrRjd6aEl6QTJrUFBlV0IxZGxZ?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?a0NzU1RDVkxrZ0pZaTFEM3RRU0JYdGo1ME1WQXdybHJtRXVsOVNsT0grRDZU?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?VjMwMkkvNWZhMHVuWnhBUmg1TnJzS1IrS20wQ3F0d0FwUlhLa3lqbUhPdlls?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?OUs0emMwVU04UHVkQ2gybDEwWW1QdEZaZWQ4dmdnMVBHU0xiVU85MCtKeDJk?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?dE1nYmVvL2liOXdjMmFRT0FmcTNGNzZaeDlGVGJHcXFYNjNRdjM5U0RqQTdx?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?OXVWRGNpRmhGWkEreFR4OHVwRXR3MXlGYzlJcDRHclhudmFBSzk3NGRHNmlU?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?b00rZWNJUCs3SjBYR3p5VVREcVFGaEs2RFpTS1VNYmxXazM2ZTF0ajN4NW9l?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?QWRjc2UyblAranZ4aVY0T3d1Wm42b0RjZkQvV1VVU05EaE9lQnh4ZU9BS1d2?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?OHh5RXpUNGZKQnRCOGdEdUpDeVdhUXUydFI2SUVZMUovK00xaUp0VjBTc2ZD?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?UEc3c1lCazNNeEF1Z0luNHN0R2RpZEZhUnRDY1ViTVFheUo0bkxrTDdyNCtu?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?Y0x6elVCVEJmVElVTWVOME5kK0N2aDVYRlR6K3pocTBIZXlWbVljR0tkNnFZ?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?bENnVXQyREUyYkpmeTN0eHRLeHdkUzV4MWM1RnZTamhFQkVneTFDZWpDNlBo?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?QUxwTmJyQkVWR0dXcXlmemttTWRCclBabW40ZEhhOW1JOUV0cUxnY1dFemw3?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?VlplNzZadzNVSWovVzgwZjhuS0pGa0lTemdrdFpYdGxOTUV2S0ZNZVBRNUtB?=\r\n =?utf-8?B?PT0=?=\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n\r\n------------=_1704903313-1077319-54\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Disposition: inline\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\nX-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.510 (Entity 5.510)\r\n\r\n\r\nto complete your tester account\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\ncomplete account sign-up\r\nhttps://accounts.tester.org/pass?userid=3D390191762&key=3D234295618-uqK=\r\nBrOjVkYE8O0DRTPfUfAWeBadbBy\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\ndidn\'t request this link?\r\n\r\n\r\nthanks for using tester =E2=98=AE\r\ntry the app: Android\r\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=3Dorg.tester.testerMo=\r\nbile\r\n|\r\n   iPhone and iPad\r\nhttps://apps.apple.com/us/app/tester/id1336642410\r\n\r\n------------=_1704903313-1077319-54\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Disposition: inline\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\nX-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.510 (Entity 5.510)\r\n\r\n<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"><p=\r\n style=3D"margin-top:43px">to complete your tester account</p>\r\n\r\n<p>\r\n<table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0"><tr>=\r\n<td><table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0"><tr><td>\r\n<a href=3D"https://accounts.tester.org/pass?userid=3D390191762&amp;key=\r\n=3D234295618-uqKBrOjVkYE8O0DRTPfUfAWeBadbBy" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"fon=\r\nt-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; te=\r\nxt-decoration: none; border-radius: 6px; background-color: #5D018F; border-=\r\ntop: 12px solid #5D018F; border-bottom: 12px solid #5D018F; border-right: 1=\r\n8px solid #5D018F; border-left: 18px solid #5D018F; display: inline-block;"=\r\n>complete account sign-up</a>\r\n</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n\r\n<p style=3D"margin-top:43px"><a href=3D"https://www.tester.org/about/he=\r\nlp/phishing?source=3Dcreate">didn\'t request this link?</a></p>\r\n\r\n\r\n<p style=3D"margin-top:46px">thanks for using tester =E2=98=AE</p>\r\n<p>try the app: <a href=3D"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=3D=\r\norg.tester.testerMobile">Android</a>\r\n   |\r\n   <a href=3D"https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tester/id1336642410">iPhone=\r\n and iPad</a>\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n------------=_1704903313-1077319-54--\r\n'
```

I get the result of this link:
`https://accounts.tester.org/pass?userid=3D390191762&key=3D234295618-uqK=BrOjVkYE8O0DRTPfUfAWeBadbBy`

Instead of this (correct link):
`https://accounts.tester.org/pass?userid=390191762&key=234295618-uqKBrOjVkYE8O0DRTPfUfAWeBadbBy`
I don't know 2 of the "3D" behind `userid` and `key` were coming from, do you know what is the problem here ?

Comment: The `"3D"` is already part of `raw_data` so it's unlikely anybody can track it down without having access to your actual email.

Comment: You didn’t do email decoding.  This is Content-Encoding: Quoted-Printable.  The easiest way to deal with this is to use the MIME Parser facilities in Python.  But the keyword for what’s going on is “Quoted Printable” if you wish to search up some background information.

Comment: @Max I don't even think it has any encoding left. When decoded to UTF-8, it looks so readable already. I will look into it

Comment: Oh sweet summer child.  Email is layers upon layers upon layers of encodings,.  Charset encoding (eg, UTF-8) is only one part of it.  There’s MIME encoding, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Encoding, Header encoding…… all to make modern concepts fit through 1970s 7-bit ascii email gateways.  Trust me here as someone who has been involved in writing email clients for the better part of a decade, stray “=3D”s are the hallmark of undecoded Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding.